# CSS for my ZoomHandlers as shown

Tags: css

I have a CSS for my ZoomHandlers as shown

.zoomHandle {
width: 10px; 
height: 55px;
}

Please see the Image of the Zoomhandlers on the chart  here 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=74ce68f

What i want to have is that , Left and Right Arrow marks on the Left and Right Zoom handlers on it , as shown here

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=bab7819

I have tried adding  background-image:("Test.png"); , but it did not got shown

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
[Css Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

You ask How?In the tutorial you see how you can display a part of a large image that you tell it zoom

```
<ul id="container">
<li id="image"></li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
#container{
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:200px;
background-image:url("background.jpg");
overflow:hidden;
}

#image{ 
position:relative;
width:1024px;
height:200px;
left:-100;
}
</style>
```

and you can have two button and with jquery increase or decrease left position of #image

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but i have only .zoomHandle {
    width: 15px; 
    height:60px; 
 background:url("/Test.png");

}  and i dont know how i can integrate all the above ??

Comment: I used this way  .zoomHandle {
position:relative;
width:150px;
height:80px;
background-image:url("Test.png");
overflow:hidden;
}   and it appeared this way 
      http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c73005e

Comment: Or can i see your complete code?just web page at client side.

Comment: Thanks , it was Very big code , anyway i used this thing only for developing http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index , Inside this there will be a Finance.css and in that css file the attribute  .zoomHandle is responsible for this